What are the steps of getting from equation 1 to equation 2?
Source: Solution key from EEE598 class handout, ASU
This problem is from a solution key to a practice test:

I am struggling to see how the teacher got from equation 1 to equation 2. I've tried using this quality factor equation:

And I know that the N=16 comes from the fact that the PLL multiplies the input frequency by 16. But I am still not able to get to equation 2. What are the steps to get from equation 1 to equation 2?

The quality factor refers to the PLL closed-loop quality factor, not the series RC quality [Source: Behzad Razavi, Design of CMOS Phase-Locked Loops, Chapter 7, Page 232]:
$$Q = \frac{1}{2\zeta} = \frac{1}{2\times \frac{R}{2}\sqrt{\frac{IK_{VCO}C}{2\pi N}}} = \frac{1}{R}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi N}{IK_{VCO}C}}$$
and for completeness:
$$\omega_0 = \sqrt{\frac{IK_{VCO}}{2\pi C N}}.$$
These equations are derived from standard loop dynamic calculation and the second-order transfer function you have is written in the canonical form using this \$Q\$.
